# Check users status

Tags: php, ajax, status

I want to make a user status system and i was thinking to have in my database a datetime field called `last_active` and update that field automatically with ajax with current time.

Then i check minutes between `last_active` and current time.. to tell if the user is online, inactive and offline..

Is this a good technique? and what happens if the user for example has the site open but is doing something else?

Is there a way to fire ajax request only if the user is viewing the page?

Comment: Just pay attention to determine the interval between the vary AJAX updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current method is a good technique to do, and the way to go,

you can check with `focusin` and `focusout` function with jquery to check if user is currently active on document or not,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $([window, document]).focusin(function(){
      // start the ajax requests
    }).focusout(function(){
      // stop the ajax requests
    });
});
```

you should take variable that will set to `true` in `focusin` function and, will set to `false` in `focusout` function. now the continues ajax request function will fire only if the variable is set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good way to check for activity. You can fire Ajax requests when the page is in focus only. I would consider using the mousemove event or similar, but also the blur/focus events can prove useful.

When the mousemove event is fired, set a variable to `true` and check thet variable before doing your Ajax request. Don't forget to reset it to `false` between each Ajax call.